# Why doesn't a return type catch excess properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Why doesn't a return type catch excess properties?

```
type TObj<K extends string> = {
    [key in K]: string;
};

type TestTObj = TObj<'g1' | 'g2'>

// 1 test
const test_obj: TestTObj = {
    g1: 'g 1',
    g2: 'g 2'
    gg: 'error' // Error
}

type fn<T> = () => T

// 2 test
const test_fn: fn<TestTObj> = () => (
    {
        g1: 'g 1',
        g2: 'g 2',
        gg: 'error' // No error
    })
```

If I use the `TestTObj` type for a constant it will complains about the extra property as expected, but for a function return type it doesn't.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg8gIwFYB4DSUIA9gQHYAmAzlEcAE4CWeA5gHxQC8UA3gFBSdQDaA1hCCjUoaALoAuUhWo0A3GwC+8tqEiwIZeMiaxEqAOQ0AjPqgAfKIYBM+umzYB6B1CNRcZNgGMA9njJuNYAB9b2RJGECtJB12LihjSUMXfQAaDi4aK0SaKBt0zhoaRIhycm9yUycoAFFS8sV7VWgAMzwUGAZmAAoASiYGGHsqqwCPHz9gUeDWyVb2yL1OqF7+5fzWdbiEyxyTNLitrJ3c1M2MossSsoqoKoA5b0w68nWFHqA)

Comment: There has to be a good dupetarget for this. Basically, TypeScript's "excess property checks" only apply to object literals assigned to an identifier or passed as an argument. Otherwise, the assumption is that a subtype (a type that matches but has extra properties) is valid.

Comment: You could catch it in your second case by explicitly typing the return, and assigning it to something before returning it: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg8gIwFYB4DSUIA9gQHYAmAzlEcAE4CWeA5gHxQC8UA3gFBSdQDaA1hCCjUoaALoAuUhWo0A3GwC+8tqEiwIZeMiaxEqAOQ0AjPqgAfKIYBM+umzYB6B1CNRcZNgGMA9njJuNYAB9b2RJGECtJB12LihjSUMXfQAaDi4aK0SaKBt0zhoaRIhycm9yUycoAFFS8sV7VWgAMzwUGAZmAAoASiYGGHsqqwCPHz9gUeDWyVb2yL1OqF7+1nyocf9yCGAANQBDABtwhe1mWLiMo2zktMuMrMscmzv7+KLLErKKqCra76geG8AHd1kp1ttgABXch4KCQg6HeRKIA)

Comment: Will try this. Thanks!